# Store and retrieve Images in MySQL Database

Tags: c#, mysql, image, visual-studio-2010, emgucv

I am doing project on face recognition using [emgu cv](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). My development environment includes visual studio 10 with c#. 
I have found a [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239849/Multiple-face-detection-and-recognition-in-real) which is easy and i can replicate it on my laptop.

This tutorial uses local directory on windows to store images and a text file for store label corresponding to image.

I want to use mysql for image storage/retrieval such that my application can use images to recognize from that database only.

Some pointers will be appreciated!

Comment: The Stackoverflow question and answer format works best when you ask a *specific* question. I think you would benefit from refining your question. In fact, it seems that you want to store and retrieve images in a mysql database using C#, and I am sure there are plenty of resources online for this already.

Comment: Brief answer for a brief question. Look at [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) [Entity Framework MySQL Tutorial](http://tinyurl.com/pmf2d2f)

Comment: @Ninjakannon, i just don't want to store/retrieve image from database, also i need to feed it to algorithm which recognize face. so how can it be achieved in real time that is what i am asking for. Thanks.

Comment: If you are asking about an issue to do with real-time constraints, you should have included that in your question. In order for anyone to help, you need to explain what the nature of the real-time constraints you have is. Are you trying to analyse all images at once/in batches, analyse individual images on request very quickly, deal with high a volume of individual recognition requests? Something else?

Comment: @SD. I'm casting a vote to close this as "too broad," though that's perhaps not going to convey the problem with this question.  The problem is that what you are asking is simple in principle but complicated in its details. To answer this question successfully and meaningfully, in a way that would be useful for future visitors, based on the amount of code you have written and have shown us so far, would essentially mean someone would have to do the work for you and then write a how-to, which suggests the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.